# If-conditionw with "+" and "-" symbol in bash

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I and new to bash scripting and have tab-delimted text file with following columns

```
A234  +  -
B654  -  +
C630  +  +
D707  -  -
```

I would like to compare traverse every line of a file and compare second and third column to get an output like following in a text file

```
A234 Plus and Minus
B654 Minus and Plus
C630 Plus and Plus
D707 Minus and Minus
```

here is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read line; 
do
g_symbol=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
t_symbol=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
if [[($g_symbol == "+") && ($t_symbol == "-")]]
then
echo $filename "PLus and Minus"
elif [[($g_symbol == "-") && ($t_symbol == "-")]]
then
echo $filename "Minus and Minus"
elif [[($g_symbol == "-") && ($t_symbol == "+")]]
then
echo $filename "Minus and Plus"
else
echo $filname "Plus and Plus"
fi
done < "$filename"
```

But when I execute it, I get the following error

```
[[(+: command not found
[[(-: command not found
[[(-: command not found
[[(+: command not found
```

Kindly guide me.

Comment: You have syntax errors in you tests. In `[[($g_symbol == "+") && ($t_symbol == "-")]]` you forgot the spaces. You need to write `[[ ($g_symbol == "+") && ($t_symbol == "-") ]]`. You need to add those spaces in all of the other tests.  Also, I don't think the `[[ ]]` tests handles nested tests.

Comment: It might be much faster to not shell out to `awk`, but `read id g_symbol t_symbol`.

Comment: @choroba How to store the value of 2 and 3rd column to the respective variables without using awk. Kindly guide me. I am new to bash

Comment: @Aserre, Thanks for your suggestion, How to output from every condition into a single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run `awk` multiple times (or at all) to extract the fields from each line. Your error, though, is because you did not put whitespace around the `[[` and `]]`. Those are, despite containing nonalphabetic characters, keywords, not part of the `if` statement's syntax.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while IFS=$'\t' read first g_symbol t_symbol; 
do
  if [[ ($g_symbol == "+") && ($t_symbol == "-") ]]
  then
    echo $filename "PLus and Minus"
  elif [[ ($g_symbol == "-") && ($t_symbol == "-") ]]
  then
    echo $filename "Minus and Minus"
  elif [[ ($g_symbol == "-") && ($t_symbol == "+") ]]
  then
    echo $filename "Minus and Plus"
  else
    echo $filname "Plus and Plus"
  fi
done < "$filename"
```

A `case` statement may be simpler:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while IFS=$'\t' read first g_symbol t_symbol; 
do
  case "$g_symbol $t_symbol" in
    "+ -") echo "$filename" "PLus and Minus" ;;
    "- -") echo "$filename" "Minus and Minus" ;;
    "- +") echo "$filename" "Minus and Plus" ;;
    "+ +") echo "$filname" "Plus and Plus" ;;
    *) echo "$filename" "Something else" ;;
  esac
done < "$filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to do using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a["+"]="Plus"; a["-"]="Minus"} {print $1, a[$2], "and", a[$3]}' file

A234 Plus and Minus
B654 Minus and Plus
C630 Plus and Plus
D707 Minus and Minus
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you'd better use `sed` or `awk` for this...

Here is an example using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\s*\([+-]\)\s*\([+-]\)/ \1 and \2/; # Add the ' and ' keyword and strip spaces
     s/\+/Plus/g;                          # Replace '+' by string 'Plus'
     s/-/Minus/g                           # Replace '-' by string 'Minus'
' file
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read line; 
do
FirstColomn=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
g_symbol=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
t_symbol=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
OutPutFileName="Output.txt"
if [[( $g_symbol == "+" ) && ( $t_symbol == "-" )]]
then
echo $FirstColomn" PLus and Minus" >>$OutPutFileName 
elif [[( $g_symbol == "-" ) && ( $t_symbol == "-") ]]
then
echo  $FirstColomn " Minus and Minus"  >>$OutPutFileName 
elif [[( $g_symbol == "-" ) && ( $t_symbol == "+" )]]
then
echo  $FirstColomn " Minus and Plus"  >>$OutPutFileName 
else
echo  $FirstColomn " Plus and Plus"  >>$OutPutFileName 
fi
done < $filename
```

Comment: Did you try it yourself?  Until you correct it, you should not recommend it to anyone, and even then, you should explain the problem and how your solution addresses that problem.